# How do I remove Windows 8 from a Ubuntu 12.10 WUBI install?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi

I have used Windows all my life, but now I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 WUBI. I'm absolutely new to Linux, and although Ubuntu is installed as dual boot along with Windows 8, I only want to use Ubuntu. How do I remove Windows 8 from my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT remove windows if you installed Ubuntu with Wubi because it is installed on the same drive of windows as a an ordinary program, you can do this if you install Ubuntu from a CD

Answer (score 0):

**Do NOT attempt to Delete a Windows installation if you have install Ubuntu via WUBI. It will leave your computer un-bootable.**

Your WUBI install is, for all effective purposes, *inside* your Windows 8 install, and as such you should not attempt to delete it. You should copy all the data (your photos, documents, videos, etc.) from the computer and on to an external device (such as a USB stick or CD). You can then install Ubuntu 12.10 from (another) DVD or USB by burning and booting them. There, you can install a new Ubuntu installation, erasing both your old Ubuntu installation *and* your Windows 8 installation.

You may wish to [follow these instructions to install Ubuntu](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/) on a separate partition.